# How does recursion unfolds when used inside a loop?

Tags: c, recursion, tree

Need to understand how **recursion** occurs in **rod cutting problem**.

Here is the code snippet:

```
int cutRod(int price[], int n)
{
   if (n <= 0)
     return 0;
   int max_val = INT_MIN;

   for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
       max_val = max(max_val, price[i] + cutRod(price, n-i-1));

   return max_val;
}
```

How would the recursion tree look like when used inside a for loop?

Comment: I see no recursion here. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And while editing, please add a language tag.

Comment: However, a good way to understand recursion is to step through the code in a debugger, while mapping it out on paper.

Comment: Sorry about that @Someprogrammerdude!!
I have updated the question ..

Comment: The same as it would if there was no loop, except it happens n times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be helpful to think about it's recurance relation. In this case it's a bit tricky because the size of the input is different in each recursive call. in this case you could use:

T(n) = T_1(n-1) + T_2(n-2) + ... T_n(0)

for example T(5) = T(4) + T(3) + T(2) + T(1) + T(0)

I'm abusing notation a bit here (this is more along the lines of what you'd use to find big Oh complexity). `+` in this case isn't actually adding anything but indicating that these calls are being made at the same level of the call stack (same recursive depth)

It should be pretty easy to draw a tree from this relation though